# init uipageviewcontroller with data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data into my UIPageViewController when it's created because it is dependent on a previous view but I'm looking at Apple's docs and there's

```
init?(coder:NSCoder)
```

but I'm not sure that's helpful.

I was wondering if there was a way to pass data to UIPageViewController  right when it's instantiated so that the UIPageViewController  is populated with the data passed in

Edit: Just a dictionary like

```
["product 1" : "product description",
 "product 2" : "product description",
]
```

It'll then be passed in to populate the views

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What kind of data? How do you wish to display it?

Comment: `UIPageViewController` is a container controller that is normally used as-is to display other view controllers as content. You may create your own subclass of `UIPageViewController` (iOS 6 and later) which will allow you to create an `init` method to set your data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not what you want, buy you could pass data between view controllers in many ways. This is one of them.

So in first view controller you could do something like this:

```
    let SecondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! ViewController
    SecondViewController.String = "Some string here"
    SecondViewController.Int = 5
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
```

And then in your second view controller, you could receive data by:

```
    var String:String?
    var Int:Int?
```

I am not sure if you could pass whole dictionary like this, but I think, that it will work! So try it out and hope it helps!

Also check this tutorial: